# Guaranteed Delivery with JMS topics and ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis, jms-topic

I'm discovering the whole JMS world, and for now every time I have tried to use a topic (pub/sub) I ultimately switched to a queue and either used a recipient-list pattern or directly performed the various computations in the consumer (which transaction-wise is not ideal, but I'm not sure if defining plenty of queues is a better practice).

I need to be sure all subscribers will get all the messages, and as I configured it that doesn't seems to be compatible with topics.

I'm using an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis configuration (so no console, which doesn't help debugging), and Spring JMS. My `broker.xml` looks as follow:

```xml
<configuration
    xmlns="urn:activemq"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-server.xsd">

    <jms xmlns="urn:activemq:jms">
    </jms>
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>

        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <!-- all queues have redelivery -->
                <redelivery-delay>200</redelivery-delay>
                <max-redelivery-delay>60000</max-redelivery-delay>
                <redelivery-delay-multiplier>1.5</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
                <redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>0.15</redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>
                <!-- all queues have dead-letters -->
                <max-delivery-attempts>10</max-delivery-attempts>
                <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

My `jmsListenerContainerFactory` is defined as follow:

```java
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(aConnectionFactory);
listenerContainerFactory.setDestinationResolver(aDestinationResolver);
listenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
listenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(JMSContext.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
listenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(aMessageConverter);
listenerContainerFactory.setTransactionManager(aTransactionManager);
return listenerContainerFactory;
```

My consumers are `@Jmslistener` annotated methods in various classes (sometime multiple for one topic in the same class if that matters).

It seems to me as if the messages are not always sent to all the consumers. Or as if the consumers would disconnect themselves from the topic while processing a message.

The behavior is consistent and happens 100% of the time on a test.

Did I missed something big, or aren't topics meant for reliable communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior. Generally speaking, a subscriber has to be *connected* to the broker in order to receive messages. This is traditional publish/subscribe semantics.

You can change this behavior by using a **durable** subscription (use `setSubscriptionDurable(true)` on your instance of `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`). However, this can be problematic if subscribers disconnect for an extended period of time as messages will accumulate in their subscriptions.

Comment: I have one monolith (for the moment) - hence the embedded setup, so no risk of having subscriber disappear on their own. After setting `subscriptionDurable=true` (and adding a clientId to my only client) my test passed! Thanks.